# How do I call a matlab code (.m file) using python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a .m matlab file which needs to be called from python. I tried using pymatlab 0.2.3 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pymatlab/files/ but, while proceeding when I reached the second step

```
session=pymatlab.session_factory()
```

I encountered an error that showed "**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument path at line 51 of sessionfactory.py"  I searched the error online and saw a solution that asked me to change line 51

```
session = MatlabSession(path=basedir,bufsize=output_buffer_size)
```

to :

```
session = MatlabSession(basedir,bufsize=output_buffer_size)
```

Even after that I could not proceed further. Can anyone help me call a .m file from python?

Comment: What's the value of `basedir`? Give the path to the `.m` file as value to `basedir` variable.

Comment: `session = MatlabSession(matlab_root='/path/to/matlab/file.m', bufsize=output_buffer_size)`, think `matlab_root` should be a directory..

Comment: @AvinashRaj  basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(executable))     this was the value given. This file came along with the pymatlpackage

Answer (score 0):

Try importing matlab.engine

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
number_of_args_out = 0 # Number of arguments the matlab program returns
eng.your_script(nargout=number_of_args_out)
```

Comment: `eng.your_script` should be my .m file name? the examples i saw for `matlab.engine` showed it calling in-built matlab functions.

Comment: If I understood right, if the .m file is placed in the same directory with the .py file it should work (Actually it is not specified, I'm just guessing it should by in the same directory). This is my source: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html)

Comment: I'm using MATLAB R2013a matlab engine is not supported by it. Do you know about mlabwrap?